# Add Authentication with external Token

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, token

I am getting the access_token from an external api (other app) but i couldn't authenticate/authorize my api using this token, here i am getting the token :

```
    [HttpPost("/authorize/user")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] LoginDTO login)
    {
        LoginDTO data = new LoginDTO 
        { 
            Email = login.Email, 
            Password = login.Password 
        };

        var stringPayload = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));

        var httpContent = new StringContent(stringPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("myrul");

            var response = client.PostAsync("auth/login", httpContent).Result;

            var payload = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())["token"];

            var access_token = payload.Value<string>("access_token");
            var refresh_token = payload.Value<string>("refresh_token");
            var expires_in = payload.Value<string>("expires_in");
            
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)

              return Ok(access_token);

            else

              return BadRequest();
        }
        
    }
```

and the startup.cs :

```
         services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.SaveToken = true;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("012345678901234567890123456789ab")),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                RequireExpirationTime = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true
            };
        });
```

the API i need to authorize :

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

but the problem its always 401 unauthorized :

[postman pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDvB4.png)

Comment: Perhaps an idea to add a JwtBearerEvent for TokenValidationFailed? Then you can check the exception details with the debugger.

Comment: More details please?

Comment: At `AddJwtBearer(x => ...` add `x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents { OnTokenValidationFailed = e => { /* check e.Exception */ return Task.CompletedTask; } };` Put the breakpoint on Task.CompletedTask and check the exception.

Comment: And you're sure the SigningKey you use matches the key used to create the token on the external api?

Comment: @BryanLewis i checked the SigningKey and it works now, thanks!!

Comment: Those kind of problems can be found when you use the bearer events to log or debug errors.